# importing domain from AWS Route S3 to Linode

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, dns-hosting, linode

I want to import a domain registered in AWS:

[image]

in the Guides: https://www.linode.com/docs/products/networking/dns-manager/guides/incoming-dns-zone-transfers/

Within your external name server, allow AXFR transfers to the following Linode IP addresses:

```
96.126.114.97
96.126.114.98
2600:3c00::5e
2600:3c00::5f
```

and also: https://www.linode.com/docs/products/networking/dns-manager/get-started/

```
ns1.linode.com
ns2.linode.com
ns3.linode.com
ns4.linode.com
ns5.linode.com
```

So I don't know which ones I should replace them with.